# Load balanced SignalR fails on start. Will Redis backplane fix?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-backplane

I'm having issues with SignalR failing to complete its connection cycle when running in a load balanced environment.  I’m exploring Redis as a means of addressing this, but want a quick sanity check that I’m not overlooking something obvious.

Symptoms –

Looking at the network traffic, I can see the **negotiate** and **connect** requests made, via XHR and websockets respectively, which is what I’d expect.  However, the **start** request fails with 
*Error occurred while subscribing to realtime feed. Error: Invalid start response: ''. Stopping the connection.*

And an error message of *({"source":null,"context":{"readyState":4, "responseText":"","status":200, "statusText":"OK"}})*

As expected, this occurs when the connect and start requests are made on different servers. Also, works 100% of the time in a non load-balanced environment.

Is this something that a Redis backplane will fix?  It seems to make sense, but most of the rational I’ve seen for adding a backplane is around hub messaging getting lost, not failing to make a connection, so I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something basic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but I believe that the backplane only allows one to send messages between the different environments user pools, it doesn't have any affect on how the connections are made or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Backplane acts as cache to pass messages to other servers behind load balancer. Connection on load balancer is a different and a tricky topic, for which I am also looking for an answer